# How can I create functions example $('#fooinput').barfunction()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

First of all excuse my not so perfect English, my question is how can I create a function for an input for example to validate something to simplify things and can call it this way $('#fooinput').barfunction(), I am something new in this topic in javascript, it is not necessary to be called with jQuery.

Comment: Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always extend jquery functions (also called plugins).

```js
$.fn.barFunction = function() {

  debugger;
  if (this.val() === "") {
    alert("Value is not valid");
  }
  
  return this;
}


$(function() {
  $("#foo").barFunction()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" value="" type="text" />
```

To know more, see:

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Edit:

Overall, its not necessary make use plugin to make any kind of validation. You can use third party libs to help you out ou use a custom for your need (Choose whatever better fit your needs)

Third party lib to help you with validation
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Or use on $.ready (build yourself)
http://form.guide/jquery/validation-using-jquery-examples.html

Comment: this was what I was looking for in a certain part, as would be an example without using jQuery is more complex?

Comment: obviously I do not want to validate a field, I wanted to know how I can start to create a complement or a "library".

Comment: Ok. I get it. Take a look at: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/learn-javascript-by-building-your-own-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a function named `barfunction` to the jQuery `$` function:

```
jQuery.fn.barfunction = function() {
    //Do something
};
```

Comment: Later I could call it using $ ('#fooinput').barfunction() right?

Comment: Yes, you could.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it will answer your question but what you can do is to create a basic plugin to jquery.

A simple example is here.

```
$.fn.barfunction = function() {
    // do something
    return this;
}
```

**Go to this link for more detail**
https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/